# Single-window outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Back in Outlook 2003, clicking on the outlook icon would bring up any already-running outlook instance. But now in Outlook 2007, clicking on the oulook icon would opens *another* outlook window.

And when you click on the outlook icon, "Open Outlook" menu will now shows a list of all the open outlook windows.

Is there a settings to turn that off? I just want a single outlook window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is thought a new feature in Outlook 2007. This way you can keep your Inbox open and still check your tasks or your calendars. You can copy drag items from one folder to another making things easier.

There is a command-line switch for opening Outlook 2007 using a shortcut:

```
/recycle
```

See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP012185891033.aspx) for details.

Comment: Well... it's a "bug" to me : - (

Answer (score 1):

When you open the second window, check in task manager to see if there are two instances running instead of just two windows of the same instance (if that makes sense).

If two instances of outlook.exe are running, you should be able to modify your shortcut and add the /recycle parameter and it should only load a single instance.

Comment: Tried this out, but there is only one OUTLOOK.EXE running. :-(