# Prevent to open multiple window of Outlook

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

In Windows 7, with Microsoft Outlook 2007 installed, when pressing the "E-Mail" key on keyboard, a new Outlook process will appear (also the same if the link into Start menu is pressed). Anyone know if is possibile to open a new Outlook the first time, then show the current open Outlook next times key (or link in Start menu) is pressed?
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I get solution for my question.
After a deep search I have found **/recycle** option for Outlook.exe (here: [Single-window outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/12741/single-window-outlook) ).

I have tried to change default Mailto windows application in registry.. Without success.
But I have found how change multimedia keyboard "mail" button behavios: open regedit, go to **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\15** (15 is standard key code for APPCOMMAND_LAUNCH_MAIL multimedia key). Here add a new string value named "**ShellExecute**" and set it to:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle
```

That's all.
Now, when pressing "mail" keyboard special key, it will display the current Outlook windows.

Comment: Any way to do this on a system that you're not allowed to break ? (corporate environment, no access to registry)

Comment: @xyious No, I'm sorry but I think there is nothing to do in this case. You have to contact the administrator of the network.

Comment: It seems like this is a very good answer. I added the keys Appkey and below that 15 and then added the string value in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\15" and it seems to be working perfectly. Thank you very much (also for commenting on a 2 year old answer).  
Obviously this only works if you're allowed to start regedit.

Comment: @xyious You had said "corporate environment, no access to registry". If your local user's privilege on PC let you open and edit the registry, obviously this trick works.
You are welcome :-)